# Encyclopedia of integers

Tags: natural-numbers, book-recommendation, integers, reference-works

Many years ago I read something that mentioned a book I would like to find. Apparently this book is sort of an encyclopedia for integers; each entry lists interesting mathematical facts about that integer. A bit like the [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/), but for individual integers.

Unfortunately, my web-searching-fu has failed me. Does this book ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: Wikipedia has articles for many positive integers that include facts like that.

Comment: this is the link to the wiki numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integers  many of them contain the note "This article may contain excessive, poor, or irrelevant examples..."

Comment: Try prime curios - has pages on lots of positive integers (prime related facts though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also "The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers" by David Weils but this does extend beyond integers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of [The Book of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785824472)?